# Jenkins shared library include java jar file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins shared library how can I import java jar class file. I have helper function written in Java and have it as jar fie. How can I include this jar file part of my Jenkins shared library?

Included jar file in `resources`  Directory but pipeline script not finding the class file. giving `unable to resolve class` error message.

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Generic way of referring a Jenkins shared library.

```
// Jenkinsfile
```

@Library('first-shared-lib')

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `libraryResource` step in your pipeline script as:

```
libraryResource './resource/abc.jar'
```